# How can we add the columns in CSharp using Compact Framework?

Tags: c#, datagrid, compact-framework, datatable

I have assigned a DataTable to a DataGrid and I want to make some columns in DataTable invisible. I am developing an application for Pocket PC. Can any one help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to make the invisible, you have to assign no style to the column you want to make it invisible